# How can I sort a generic array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, generics

I have an generic array(it keeps set of element and element of type is generic(maybe int,maybe char, maybe String etc.)

And also I think a set is sorted so I wanted to use bubblesort algorithm.But 
I took  `// bad operand types for binary operator '>'` this error message.

What can I do for this sort function work some different data type(String,int,char,double)

This is my code :

```
void bubbleSort(T arr[]){
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){
             if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]){  // bad operand types for binary operator '>'              
                  T temp = arr[j];
                  arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                  arr[j+1] = temp;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Edit1:

If I tried compareTo:

```
void bubbleSort(T arr[]){
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){
             if (arr[j].compareTo(arr[j+1])<0){  // bad operand types for binary operator '>'              
                  T temp = arr[j];
                  arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                  arr[j+1] = temp;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

The error message is :

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method compareTo(T)
  location: class Object
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class MySet
```

---

Edit2 :
If I tried this:

```
<T extends Comparable<T>> void  bubbleSort(T arr[]) {
int n = arr.length;
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){
         if (arr[j].compareTo(arr[j+1])> 0) {
              T temp = arr[j];
              arr[j] = arr[j+1];
              arr[j+1] = temp;
         }
     }
}
```

}

When calling the function bubbleSort:

```
private T[] data;
bubbleSort(data);
```

The error message is :

```
method bubbleSort in class Set<T#2> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: T#1[]
  found: T#2[]
  reason: inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
    upper bounds: Comparable<T#1>
    lower bounds: T#2
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in method <T#1>bubbleSort(T#1[])
    T#2 extends Object declared in class Set
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

---

Edit3:

If I try this:

```
void bubbleSort(Comparable arr[]) {
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){
             if (arr[j].compareTo(arr[j+1])> 0) {
                  Comparable temp = arr[j];
                  arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                  arr[j+1] = temp;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

And call the function bubbleSort :

```
   private T[] data;
    bubbleSort(data);
```

The error message is:

```
incompatible types: T[] cannot be converted to Comparable[]
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class MySet
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

Comment: Use `compareTo()` instead

Comment: Make `T` implement [Comparable<T>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and use `compareTo`.

Comment: @FrankUnderwood I tried but I didn't work, see my edited post

Comment: @tarktark see the answers below. You need to bound the type parameter

Answer (score 3):

You *can't*, unless you know that they're at least `Comparable`.  You can't use inequality operators on an object, since they're not guaranteed to autobox to primtives.

At a minimum your generic type should be `Comparable`:

```
public class Sorter<T extends Comparable<T>> { }
```

...and you should look into `compareTo`, an exercise I leave for the reader.

Comment: @tarktark:  That's quite literally as specific as you need to get.  Here's another hint:  I didn't know what your class was called, so I went with `Sorter`.  I can see from your stack trace that it's called `GTUSet`.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead use

```
arr[j].compareTo(arr[j+1]) > 0
```

but this requires that `T` is `Comparable`, in which case the function signature should be like this:

```
void bubbleSort(Comparable arr[])
```

Comment: Would this be better practice then bounding the type parameter?

Comment: After that what should I do, can you write spesific code?

Comment: @tarktark I already wrote the two specific lines of code that should change. What else are you looking for?

Comment: Could you see edit3 in my post ? I write your lines of code but it doesn't work

Comment: @tarktark The `data` you are passing in is not `Comparable`. You need to declare `private Comparable[] data;`

Comment: @PeterOlson but `data` is a generic type If I do this, I take a lot of error message in my code.

Comment: @tarktark It's impossible to sort a generic type because there's no way to know how to compare arbitrary data. In order to use `compareTo` the argument has to implement `Comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer - you can't. In order to be able to sort an array, you need the ability to compare between every two elements, which simply isn't possible with every class.

One option is to limit yourself to [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

```
<T extends Comparable<T>> void  bubbleSort(T arr[]) {
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){
             if (arr[j].compareTo(arr[j+1])) > 0 {
                  T temp = arr[j];
                  arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                  arr[j+1] = temp;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can allow the caller to supply their own [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
<T> void  bubbleSort(T arr[], Comparator<T> cmp) {
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){
             if (cmp.compare(arr[j], arr[j+1])) > 0 {
                  T temp = arr[j];
                  arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                  arr[j+1] = temp;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: for first option , how can I call this function?

Comment: @tarktark with any array of a class that implements `Comparable`. E.g.: `String arr = new String[]{"stack", "overflow"}; bubbleSort(arr);`.

Comment: @tarktark The `T` in `T[]` is not a `Comparable` in the snippet you shared.

Comment: @tarktark the same level that defines `T[]`  (presumably the class) should define `T` as `T extends Comparable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a insertion sort that works for generics. I'm a java noob but I swear once I changed my .equals **in the object I was using to test the generic class** to correctly overload the object class it worked.
Here is my .equals:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj != null && getClass() == obj.getClass()) {
            Transaction q = (Transaction)obj;
            return getValue() == q.getValue() && getDate().equalsIgnoreCase(q.getDate()) && getProvider().equalsIgnoreCase(q.getProvider());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Check [this link](https://help.semmle.com/wiki/display/JAVA/Overloaded+equals) for a simpler example.

Here is my insertion sort. I'm just using the object from my lab I'm doing right now.

```
private void insertionSort(){

        T temp;
        for (int i = 1; i < numElements; i++) {
            for(int j = i ; j > 0 ; j--){
                if (((Comparable)list[j]).compareTo(list[j-1]) < 0) {
                    temp = list[j];
                    list[j] = list[j-1];
                    list[j-1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
```

Please excuse my ignorance in terms of the .equals idea, but I just wanted to throw it out there. I was making a lot of changes and am probably just confused.

Also, I just declared the class `public class MyArrayUnsortedList<T>` rather than `public class MyArrayUnsortedList<T extends Comparable<T>>` if that makes a difference.